# Object.equals(Boolean, Boolean) vs Logical Operators (Java)

Tags: java, object, boolean, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

First of all, apologies to this very basic question. I'm fairly new to stackoverflow but I'm scratching my head over this and would like some enlightenment.

Okay, so today at work me and my colleague's code was peer reviewed and was told to replace this..

```
Boolean isOpen;
*some processing that involves altering the value of isOpen*
if (!isOpen){
...
}
```

with this..

```
if (Objects.equals(Boolean.FALSE, isOpen)){
...
}
```

I get it that both implementation is correct and produces the same result. I also know the consequences of using the `Boolean` object wrappper.

What I don't get it the difference between using the NOT operator and Objects.equals() in this context. I know that at runtime the `isOpen` will be unboxed. Both are still susceptible to a `NullPointerException` so what's the difference? It kinda beats the purpose of logical operators.

Comment: what AND operator are you talking about?

Comment: "Both are still susceptible to a `NullPointerException`". Not really. The second one won't throw `NullPointerException` if `isOpen` is null.

Comment: Why is `isOpen` a tri-boolean? It sure doesn't sound like it should be one. What's the state of the program when it's null? Half open?

Comment: @Stultuske, sorry that was a NOT operator. I was nervous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no `static` `equals` method in `Object` class.

You probably meant `Objects.equals()`. The advantage of using `Objects.equals(Boolean.FALSE, isOpen)` instead of `!isOpen` is to avoid `NullPointerException` when `isOpen` is `null`.

That said, I'd rather change `isOpen` from `Boolean` to `boolean` if possible, and keep the `!isOpen` condition.

Comment: Sorry, that was `Objects.equals`. I didn't really think of when `isOpen` is going to be null. But when it does, now that @Pavel Smirnov mentioned it, Objects.equals won't throw a `NullPointerException` because if `isOpen` is null, the equals comparison will just fail and return a false value.

Comment: Using `Objects.equals(Boolean.FALSE, isOpen)` is unnecessary, as `Boolean.FALSE.equals(isOpen)` is also null-safe and shorter. Using `Object.equals` is primarily for cases where either (or both) can be null.